# Memory leak in a tree?

Tags: java, memory-management

I'm running a dual-machine job-scheduling algorithm simulation. Currently I'm at 2 machines with 10 jobs each, and I'm already running out of memory... My assignment goal is to run 2 machines with 20 jobs each; from the looks of it, I'm really really far from that goal. So I hope you can give me all the tips and tricks into memory management. Please, feel free to throw anything at me.

Class that defines attributes of a Job

```
public class Job {
final static int WAITING = 0;
final static int ASSIGNED = 1;
final static int COMPLETE = 2;

int num;
int machine;
int time;
int weight;
int due;
int resUse;
int resGain;

int parent;
int status = 0;//0:incomplete 1:assigned 2:complete

public Job() {
}

public Job(int num, int machine, int time, int weight, int due, int resUse, int resGain, int parent, int status) {
    super();
    this.num = num;
    this.time = time;
    this.machine = machine;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.due = due;
    this.resUse = resUse;
    this.resGain = resGain;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.status = status;
}


public String toString() {
    return "n=" + num + " m=" + machine + " t=" + time + " w=" + weight + " d=" + due + " a=" + resUse + " b=" + resGain + " p=" + parent + " s=" + status;
}
}
```

This is my "node" class

```
public class Machine {

int job[] = new int[Algo.NUM_MACHINES];
int remTime[] = new int[Algo.NUM_MACHINES];
int res = Algo.RESOURCE;
int time = 0;
int tardy = 0;

//Job jobTree[] = new Job[Algo.NUM_JOBS];
ArrayList<Integer> jobsFinished = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int id;
boolean visited = false;
Machine parent = this;//so that root node points to himself
ArrayList<Machine> children = new ArrayList<Machine>();

int duplicate = 0;//duplicate (sj-sj-sj-sj-...) flag

public Machine() {
    jobsFinished.add(0);
}

/**
 * cloning constructor
 * @param shadow
 */
public Machine(Machine shadow) {
    this.job = shadow.job.clone();
    this.remTime = shadow.remTime.clone();
    this.res = shadow.res;
    this.time = shadow.time;
    this.tardy = shadow.tardy;
    this.parent = shadow;
    this.duplicate = shadow.duplicate;
    this.jobsFinished.addAll(shadow.jobsFinished);

}

/**
 * method used to obtain machine state
 * @return 0 if both machines are idle, 1 if one machine is busy, and 2 if both machines are
 *         busy
 */
public int getMachineState() {
    if (remTime[0] == 0 && remTime[1] == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (remTime[0] != 0 && remTime[1] != 0)
        return 2;
    else
        return 1;
}

public String toString() {
    String jobStr = " job[]=";
    for (int i = 0; i < job.length; i++)
        jobStr += job[i] + " ";
    String timeStr = "rem[]=";
    for (int i = 0; i < remTime.length; i++)
        timeStr += remTime[i] + " ";

    return "id=" + id + jobStr + timeStr + "time=" + time + " parent=" + parent.id + " tardy=" + tardy + " res=" + res + " dup=" + duplicate;
}
}
```

I present the poorly-written algorithm:

```
public class Algo {
final static int NUM_MACHINES = 2;
final static int NUM_JOBS = 20 + 1;
final static int RESOURCE = 15;

final int LOWER_BOUND = 1;
final int DUPLICATE = 1;

/*
p11 = 3    w11 = 7     d11 = 16    alpha = 3   beta = 6
p12 = 6    w12 = 1     d12 = 11    alpha = 7   beta = 16
p13 = 8    w13 = 3     d13 = 15    alpha = 8   beta = 3
p21 = 5    w21 = 6     d21 = 8     alpha = 7   beta = 3
p22 = 4    w22 = 10    d22 = 6     alpha = 6   beta = 2
 */
final Job jobTree[] = { new Job(0, 0, 999, 0, 999, 999, 0, 0, Job.COMPLETE),
        new Job(1, 0, 95, 1, 246, 9, 8, 0, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(2, 0, 10, 6, 184, 8, 6, 1, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(3, 0, 63, 4, 367, 3, 9, 2, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(4, 0, 71, 9, 353, 18, 19, 3, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(5, 0, 10, 1, 305, 7, 14, 4, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(6, 0, 97, 7, 239, 3, 2, 5, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(7, 0, 83, 2, 132, 4, 5, 6, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(8, 0, 24, 2, 354, 5, 10, 7, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(9, 0, 59, 5, 371, 15, 2, 8, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(10, 0, 10, 2, 260, 1, 15, 9, Job.WAITING),

        new Job(11, 1, 36, 7, 145, 3, 13, 0, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(12, 1, 88, 6, 270, 13, 19, 11, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(13, 1, 30, 4, 229, 10, 16, 12, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(14, 1, 47, 7, 118, 11, 6, 13, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(15, 1, 88, 3, 180, 11, 19, 14, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(16, 1, 40, 2, 141, 1, 9, 15, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(17, 1, 18, 6, 245, 17, 5, 16, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(18, 1, 18, 8, 250, 17, 18, 17, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(19, 1, 6, 6, 207, 8, 6, 18, Job.WAITING),
        new Job(20, 1, 53, 5, 159, 5, 6, 19, Job.WAITING) };

ArrayList<Machine> mLeastTardy = new ArrayList<Machine>();
Machine mRoot;
int index = 0;
int minTardy = 99999;

ArrayList<HashMap> mDuplicate = new ArrayList<HashMap>();

public void init() {
    System.out.println("advAlgo3");
    mRoot = new Machine();
    mRoot.id = index++;
    //mState.add(root);
}

public void run() throws Exception {
    init();

    //int minTardyStateIndex = 0;

    Machine state = mRoot;
    Machine minTardyState = null;

    //begin algorithm
    while (true) {
        //System.out.println("run() " + state);
        if (state.visited == false) {

            switch (state.getMachineState()) {
                case 0://both machines are free
                    for (Job job : jobTree)
                        scheduleJob(state, job);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    scheduleWork(state);
                    for (Job job : jobTree)
                        scheduleJob(state, job);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    scheduleWork(state);
                    break;
            }

            state.visited = true;
        }

        //begin min-tardy analysis
        if (state.jobsFinished.size() == NUM_JOBS) {//if all jobs are finished
            if (state.tardy < minTardy) {//if the schedule is least tardy
                minTardyState = state;
                minTardy = minTardyState.tardy;

                mLeastTardy.clear();//renew the leastTardy path
                while (minTardyState.id != 0) {
                    mLeastTardy.add(minTardyState);
                    minTardyState = minTardyState.parent;
                }
            }
        }

        //garbage collection
        if (state.children.isEmpty()) {//if this is a leaf node (no children)
            state.parent.children.remove(state);
        }

        //traverse to the next node
        Machine nextState = state.parent;//default is to traverse up
        for (Machine childState : state.children) {
            if (childState.visited == false) {//but if you can find a child that hasn't been visited yet
                nextState = childState;//traverse down
                break;
            }
        }
        state = nextState;

        //when all nodes have been traversed
        if (nextState.id == 0) {//if traverse back to root
            boolean finish = true;
            for (Machine child : nextState.children) {
                if (child.visited == false)//if root still has an unvisited child
                    finish = false;
            }
            if (finish == true) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }//end algorithm

    /*
    //begin backward analysis
    ArrayList<Machine> minTardy = new ArrayList<Machine>();
    while (minTardyState.id != 0) {
        minTardy.add(minTardyState);
        minTardyState = minTardyState.parent;
    }*/

    //print path & gnatt chart
    String gnattChart[] = new String[Algo.NUM_MACHINES];
    for (int i = 0; i < gnattChart.length; i++)
        gnattChart[i] = "";
    state = mRoot;

    for (int i = mLeastTardy.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Machine nextState = mLeastTardy.get(i);
        System.out.println(nextState);

        for (int j = 0; j < Algo.NUM_MACHINES; j++) {
            if (nextState.remTime[j] == 0) {
                int t = nextState.time - state.time;
                for (int k = 0; k < Algo.NUM_MACHINES; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < t; l++) {
                        if (state.job[k] < 10)
                            gnattChart[k] += state.job[k];
                        else {
                            gnattChart[k] += '#';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        state = nextState;
    }
    System.out.println("# of Nodes=" + index);
    System.out.println("# of Duplicates=" + mDuplicate.size());
    System.out.println("Gnatt chart:");
    for (String gnatt : gnattChart) {
        System.out.println(gnatt);
    }

    //generateGraph();

}

private void scheduleJob(Machine parent, Job job) {
    if (parent.res >= job.resUse) {//if there's enough resource to run the job
        if (parent.remTime[job.machine] == 0) {//if the dedicated machine is idle
            if (parent.jobsFinished.contains(job.parent)) {//if the preceeding job is complete
                if (!parent.jobsFinished.contains(job.num)) {//but this isn't

                    //create a copy of the current state
                    Machine child = new Machine(parent);
                    child.id = index++;
                    //assign the job to the machine
                    child.job[job.machine] = job.num;
                    //set the machine's running time
                    child.remTime[job.machine] = job.time;
                    //deduct the resources
                    child.res -= job.resUse;
                    //update the job tree
                    //child.jobTree[job.num].status = Job.ASSIGNED;
                    //duplicate analysis
                    if (DUPLICATE == 1) {
                        child.duplicate++;
                        if (child.duplicate == NUM_MACHINES) {//if sj-sj
                            boolean new_dup = true;
                            for (HashMap dupmap : mDuplicate) {//compare against duplicate list
                                if (child.time == (Integer) dupmap.get("time")) {
                                    int num_dup = 0;
                                    for (int jNum : child.job) {
                                        if (((ArrayList<Integer>) dupmap.get("dupJob")).contains(jNum)) {
                                            num_dup++;
                                        } else {
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (num_dup == NUM_MACHINES) {
                                        child.visited = true;
                                        new_dup = false;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            if (new_dup) {//if this is a new combo, append this combo to the duplicate list

                                ArrayList<Integer> dup = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                                for (int jNum : child.job) {
                                    dup.add(jNum);
                                }
                                HashMap dupmap = new HashMap();
                                dupmap.put("time", child.time);
                                dupmap.put("dupJob", dup);
                                //System.out.println(dupmap);
                                mDuplicate.add(dupmap);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //
                    parent.children.add(child);
                    //System.out.println("sj() " + child + " # " + job);
                    //add this state to the tree
                    //mState.add(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void scheduleWork(Machine parent) {
    //find the machine with the shortest remaining processing time
    int shortestTime = 99999;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MACHINES; i++) {
        if (parent.remTime[i] < shortestTime && parent.remTime[i] != 0) {
            shortestTime = parent.remTime[i];
        }
    }

    //schedule Work node for ALL machines working on a job with the shortest remaining processing time
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MACHINES; i++) {
        if (parent.remTime[i] == shortestTime) {//if this machine is working on a job with the shortest remaining processing time
            Job finishingJob = jobTree[parent.job[i]];

            //create a copy of the current state
            Machine child = new Machine(parent);
            child.id = index++;
            //move the time pointer forward
            child.time += shortestTime;
            //increase tardiness
            if (child.time > finishingJob.due) {
                child.tardy += (child.time - finishingJob.due) * finishingJob.weight;
            }
            if (LOWER_BOUND == 1) {
                if (child.tardy > minTardy) {
                    child.visited = true;
                }
            }
            //return resources
            child.res += finishingJob.resGain;
            //free the machine
            child.job[i] = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_MACHINES; j++)
                if (child.remTime[j] > 0)
                    child.remTime[j] -= shortestTime;
            //update the job tree
            child.jobsFinished.add(finishingJob.num);
            //reset the duplicate flag
            if (DUPLICATE == 1) {
                child.duplicate = 0;
            }
            //
            parent.children.add(child);
            //System.out.println("sw() " + child);

            //add the state to the tree
            //mState.add(child);
        }
    }
}
/*
    private void generateGraph() throws Exception {
        Undirectgraph ug = new Undirectgraph();
        int stateNum = mState.size();
        ug.createMatrix(stateNum);

        for (int i = 0; i < stateNum; i++) {
            int childNum = mState.get(i).children.size();
            for (int j = 0; j < childNum; j++)
                ug.addEdge(i + 1, mState.indexOf(mState.get(i).children.get(j)) + 1, mState.get(i).children.get(j).tardy);
        }

        System.out.println(ug.toGraphviz());
    }*/
}
```

And finally the main class that executes the algorithm

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Algo program = new Algo();
    program.run();
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try profiling your application?

Comment: No, I did not. What is it and are there any tutorials/topics/resources on that?

Comment: Basically, profiling is inspecting the CPU and memory usage of your application at runtime. I can recommend VisualVM which comes free with a JDK. Check [this link](http://visualvm.java.net/description.html) for a short introduction.

Comment: Whoops, I sent you an old link. I guess [this link](http://visualvm.java.net/gettingstarted.html) is better. There also used to be a great tutorial on using visualvm to check for memory leaks, but I can't find it at the moment. I guess you have to google yourself for that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, found the leak. Just want to answer myself to close this question.

I delete a child through

```
    //garbage collection
    if (state.children.isEmpty()) {//if this is a leaf node (no children)
        state.parent.children.remove(state);
    }
```

And the leak happens at every

```
    if (some_condition) {
        child.visited = true;
    }
```

If a node is prematurely set to be visited, I will not be able traverse to that node and check if the node's children is empty or not. Resulting in the node not being recycled.

Viola.

Comment: perhaps share what the leak was in this answer so it can be of use to others in a more general sense

Comment: No problem, but after I finish running my assignments!!